# Why has GridLayout been moved to the legacy tab? What to use instead?

Tags: android, android-studio, legacy, android-gridlayout

I'm taking a fairly recent course on android development, and it uses `GridLayout` a few times during the course. However, I've noticed that `GridLayout` has been moved to the Legacy tab of Android Studio since the time of recording (I'm using Android Studio 4.1 now). My questions are:

1. Why is `GridLayout` legacy now? what was wrong with it?
2. What layout should you use instead? I'm imagining there was a layout that could provide similar functionality to `GridLayout` which justified moving it to the legacy tab. The only thing I can think of is the `TableLayout`, but mimicing `GridLayout`s features with it is not always intuitive for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079230/15160601

Comment: @zoldxk Thanks, I had already seen that link, but the problem is that it discusses all the Legacy items except ```GridLayout```. (There is some mention of ```GridView``` though, which is not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: Link to same question: [why-are-some-views-located-inside-the-legacy-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079026/why-are-some-views-located-inside-the-legacy-tab-in-android-studio-3-1-and-what)